# Using zf-tool with xampp and Windows 7

Tags: zend-framework, command-line

I'm new to Zend Framework and i'm trying to do some tests on my local server. I use xampp on a Windows 7 pc.

So i downloaded the zend package who comes with a command line tool to setting up projects. Copied the folder with zf.sh on the hard-drive on the location C:\Program Files (x86)\ZendFrameworkCli\bin, than updated the system variables to make it work.

When i type in the command line "zf show version" i get an error by "php.exe". I guess this happens becouse php and apache are not installed on the OS but runs under xampp server.

So, there's any way to make it work with xampp? Thanx in advance.

Comment: please post the error message

Comment: @ArneRie: "php.exe" is not recognized as a command, a executable program or a file batch. (This is a bad translation from my language, hope it could describe the problem...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to had the php executable path to you PATH variable. You can do this with the system icon in your configuration panel. You can also use a nice utility : RedmondPath ( http://sites.google.com/site/redmondlab/path)

After that, launch a command prompt and type `php -v` to make sure that all is correct.